# asyncpg/fastapi creating more connection than pool limit

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, asyncpg

I was doing some testing on our fastapi platform and it basically pushed our DB to 100% CPU. Upon closer investigation, it seems like our app was maxing the DB connections(currently 100).

In our script, we have the following connection file(and you can see we limit to 30) so it should haven't had 100 connections. Also I was only testing with one server so it came from the server.

Here is my DB connection file:

```
import asyncpg
class Database:
    def __init__(self, database: str, user: str, password: str, host: str, port: int = 5432):
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.database = database
        self._cursor = None

        self._connection_pool = None
        self.con = None

    async def connect(self):
        if not self._connection_pool:
            try:
                self._connection_pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
                    min_size=1,
                    max_size=30,
                    command_timeout=300,
                    host=self.host,
                    port=self.port,
                    user=self.user,
                    password=self.password,
                    database=self.database,
                )

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    
    async def disconnect(self):
        if self._connection_pool:
            try:
                await self._connection_pool.close()
                self._connection_pool = None
                self.con = None
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

    async def fetch_rows(self, query: str, *args):
        if not self._connection_pool:
            await self.connect()
        else:
            con = await self._connection_pool.acquire()
            try:
                result = await con.fetch(query, *args)
                return result
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            finally:
                await self._connection_pool.release(con)

    async def execute(self, query: str):
        if not self._connection_pool:
            await self.connect()
        else:
            con = await self._connection_pool.acquire()
            try:
                result = await con.execute(query)
                return result
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            finally:
                await self._connection_pool.release(con)
```

then we create a session with this:

```
from db_connection import Database
from config import config

main_db_instance = Database(
    database=config.postgres_main_db_name,
    host=config.postgres_server,
    user=config.postgres_user,
    password=config.postgres_password
)
```

Then we call main_db_instance to query the DB. My understanding even if we make 500 requests at the same time, the pooling option we set should limit the active connections to the DB to 30.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe every session create own instance of `Database()` and then every session has own limit 30. First you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed.

Comment: Yes the easiest way to check if you have only one `main_db_instance` would be `print()` function. Also many workers/duplications of pods/containers might create many of such instances.